# Is there a proper way to abort a sidekiq job to make it retry?

Tags: sidekiq

I have a Sidekiq job that communicates with a number of external services. At any time, one or more of those services could be unavailable. If I catch the exception when the service is unavailable, how can I, in turn, raise an exception or end processing so the job is placed in the retry queue? Ultimately, I want to eliminate the noise of these "expected" exceptions being caught by the likes of BugSnag and Sentry so I can focus on real exceptions.

Suggestions? Gists?

Comment: http://docs.honeybadger.io/ruby/getting-started/ignoring-errors.html

Comment: Mike, are you saying the HoneyBadger gem can be used to squelch those errors even if the service I am using is BugsSnag?

Comment: Nope, just a possible direction for you to investigate.  I suspect BugSnag has similar functionality but I didn't know which service you use.

Comment: BugSnag does have similar filtering options. Refer to https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/ruby/rails/configuration-options/#ignore_classes

Comment: I wrote this... https://gist.github.com/martinstreicher/98ae3a3b4514856ec4ffd70b07487bc7